# Как создать сайт карты мира, что бы когда наводишь на страну или город показывало погоду?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, как создать сайт на подобии этого openweathermap.org/weathermap
Сайт, получаеться сделать, не могу понять как сделать что бы при наведении на город появлялась погода(точнее как привязать ее к нужному городу). Может у кого есть похожие материалы, или знает где искать. Спасибо

Comment: теоретически тебе надо города метками на карте проставить, или тому подобное, или знать координаты городов, при наведении на которые выводить поп-ап.

Comment: Названия населённых пунктов можно получать [обратным геокодированием](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/). OpenWeatherMap умеет отдавать погоду [как по названию страны и города, так и по координатам](http://openweathermap.org/current)

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере при наведении на страну отображается информация. Думаю при желании можно сделать и по городам так. Вот полная информация:

[Визуализация геоданных в D3.js](http://frontender.info/d3js-map-visualization/)

[Дополнительные материалы по картам](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Согласен, в данном случае не добавил пример потому что он слишком объёмный, пожалел времени на оформление. Статья и правда очень большая, с множеством примеров. Может есть какой то способ добавить html готовой статьи сюда, чтобы не сидеть несколько часов над оформлением?